# Getting SSL to work in AWS on Ghost by bitnami

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, ssh, bitnami

I am stuck on step 4 with using SSH to enable https

https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/how-to/configure-elb-ssl-aws/

I open putty to make an SSH
I type /opt/bitnami/apps/ghost/conf/httpd-prefix.conf

the SSH client tells me -bash:/opt/bitnami/apps/ghost/conf/httpd-prefix.conf: permission denied
Can anyone provide a more detailed instruction into how to get my SSL certificate to work with Ghost by bitnami on AWS
Thank you

Comment: Have you elevated your privileges to root before trying to modify the file?

Comment: I have not nor do I know how to. Total noob at this and trying to figure it out though google searches

Comment: I posted an answer that should help guide you. Let me know if you have more questions and I'll try my best.

Answer (score 0):

There's two things you need to do. First, you have to launch an editor to modify the `httpd-prefix.conf` file. [Nano](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/42980/the-beginners-guide-to-nano-the-linux-command-line-text-editor/) is easy to use and should be installed on your instance already. Issue a command like `nano /opt/bitnami/apps/ghost/conf/httpd-prefix.conf`, make your edits in the nano editor, then save the file.

The second thing is to make sure that the account you are using has permissions to perform those tasks. You'll need [root-level permissions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superuser). You can use the [sudo](https://linuxacademy.com/blog/linux/linux-commands-for-beginners-sudo/) command to run things as root. If you get a permission denied error when launching nano, try `sudo nano /opt/bitnami/apps/ghost/conf/httpd-prefix.conf` and enter the necessary password to execute the nano command with root privileges.

Keep in mind that the [best practice for AWS accounts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html) is to only use the root account to create your first IAM user, so that your root account credentials stay safe, and that hackers can't gain full control of your account should a compromise happen.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance still struggling, I typed nano / opt/…….

Comment: Thank you for the assistance still struggling, I typed nano / opt/…….            then in the file I typed SetEnvIf…..    When I reaccess the file below the SetEnvIf line is include file Rewrite engine On                                                  RewriteCond "%[HTTP_Host' ^ec2 - (code I think interprets into an IP or something)                                                                                                     RewriteRule more "code"                                                         Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/ghost/conf/httpd-app.conf"

Answer (score 0):

Instead try this for setting up an SSL cert https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/how-to/generate-install-lets-encrypt-ssl/